# Ansible resetting swap on linux

Tags: linux, swap, ansible

I am newbie to Ansible, i failed using ansible via command that way :

```
ansible host -a "/sbin/swapoff -a && /sbin/swapon -a"
```

Only this worked

```
ansible host -a "/sbin/swapoff -a
ansible host -a "/sbin/swapon -a
```

I am thinking of making a playbook, starting maybe with this:

```
- name: Turn off swap
  shell : "swapoff -a"

- name: Turn on swap
  shell : "swapon -a"
```

I would like to **reset swap space** with a condition, only when the swap used space is **greater** than **100mb**. Is it possible to do that ?

Many thanks for your help

Comment: You need to use the `shell` or `command` modules to execute stuff with pipes, logical operators etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How to reset swap space when used swap is greater than 100mb**

There are multiple ways to do this. Here is one way that will introduce you to some basic Ansible concepts.

First, grab the swap space from the system:

```
- name: Grab the swap space used (in megabytes)
  shell: free -m | grep Swap | awk '{print $2}'
  register: swap_used
```

Then, only toggle the swap on and off if the swap_space is greater than the threshold.

```
- name: Turn off swap
  shell: "swapoff -a"
  when: (swap_used.stdout_lines[0] | int) > 100

- name: Turn on swap
  shell : "swapon -a"
  when: (swap_used.stdout_lines[0] | int) > 100
```

Comment: I tried to learn and use ansible_facts for this case but it doesn't worked, i was doing something wrong


- hosts: hostnametest
  tasks:
    - name: Activate-Dsactivate swap
      shell : "swapoff -a && swapon -a"
      when: ansible_swapfree_mb < 1800


Your solution is working well, you really make my day, thank you so much :) Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Using facts:

```
- name: Reset swap 
  shell: "swapoff -a && swapon -a"
  when: ansible_memory_mb['swap']['total'] > 100
```